# $A.CreateComponents callback is not working

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, create-component

The issue is that createComponents method is being invoked but the $A.CreateComponents callback is not getting executed

controller

```
 ({
        doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
            var params = new Object();
            params['strFieldSetName'] = 'Test_Fieldset';
            helper.callServer(component,'c.getFormInputWrp',params,helper.getFormInputWrpCallback,helper);
        }
    })
```

helper

```
({
    callServer : function(component,method,params,callback,self){
        var action = component.get(method);
        action.setParams(params);
        this.executePromise(action,component).then(function(response){
            var state = response.getState();
            if (state === "SUCCESS") {
                component.set('v.lstDynamicCmpInputWrpVar',response.getReturnValue().lstDynamicCmpInputWrp);
                component.set('v.lstMandatoryFields',response.getReturnValue().lstMandatoryFields);
                self.CreateDynamicArrayAndComponent(component,response.getReturnValue().lstDynamicCmpInputWrp,self);
            }
            else if (state === "ERROR") 
                console.log(response.getError());
        });
    },
    executePromise : function(action,component){
        return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            action.setCallback(this,function(response) {
                var state = response.getState();
                if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS")
                    resolve(response);
                else if (component.isValid() && state === "ERROR")
                    reject(response.getError());
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
        });
    },
    getFormInputWrpCallback : function(response,component,self){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set('v.lstDynamicCmpInputWrpVar',response.getReturnValue().lstDynamicCmpInputWrp);
            component.set('v.lstMandatoryFields',response.getReturnValue().lstMandatoryFields);
            this.CreateDynamicArrayAndComponent(component,response.getReturnValue().lstDynamicCmpInputWrp,self);
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR") 
            console.log(response.getError());
    },
    CreateDynamicArrayAndComponent : function(component,lstDynamicCmpInputWrp,self){
        var componentArray = new Array();
        var componentName = "lightning:inputField";
        for(var i=0;i<lstDynamicCmpInputWrp.length;i++)
            componentArray.push([
                componentName , 
                this.createAttributesObject(component,lstDynamicCmpInputWrp[i])
            ]);
        console.log(componentArray);
        self.createComponents(component,componentArray);
    },
    createAttributesObject : function(component,objFieldSetMember){
        var obj = new Object();
        obj.value = component.getReference('v.objTestAccount.'+objFieldSetMember.APIName);
        obj.fieldName = objFieldSetMember.APIName; 
        return obj;
    },
    createComponents : function(component,componentArray){
        console.log('createComponents');
        $A.createComponents(
            componentArray,
            function(objDynCmp, status, errorMessage){
                console.log('component Creation  '+status);
                if (status === "SUCCESS")
                    component.set("v.body",objDynCmp);
                else 
                    console.log(status);
            }
        );
    }
})
```

Comment: Any errors on the console? I think you're going to have to do some more debugging; your code is very non-JavaScript-like, and while I don't see any immediate errors, I'm also not entirely surprised it doesn't work.

Comment: @sfdcfox do i have to improve the way i write Javascript code.If yes, how do i improve can you please review what changes can i do in the mentioned code in this post

Answer (score 1):

The issue got resolved I forgot to put $A.getCallback in the then part of the Promise

Controller

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        var params = new Object();
        params['strFieldSetName'] = 'Test_Fieldset';
        helper.callServer(component,'c.getFormInputWrp',params,helper.getFormInputWrpCallback,helper);
    }
})
```

Helper

```
({
    callServer : function(component,method,params,callback,helper){
        var action = component.get(method);
        action.setParams(params);
        this.executePromise(action,component).then(
            $A.getCallback(function(response) {
                callback(response,component,helper);
            })
        );
    },
    executePromise : function(action,component){
        return new Promise(function(resolve,reject){
            action.setCallback(this,function(response){
                var state = response.getState();
                if (component.isValid() && state === "SUCCESS")
                    resolve(response);
                else if (component.isValid() && state === "ERROR")
                    reject(response.getError());
            });
            $A.enqueueAction(action);
        });
    },
    getFormInputWrpCallback : function(response,component,helper){
        var state = response.getState();
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            component.set('v.lstDynamicCmpInputWrpVar',response.getReturnValue().lstDynamicCmpInputWrp);
            component.set('v.lstMandatoryFields',response.getReturnValue().lstMandatoryFields);
            helper.CreateDynamicArrayAndComponent(component,response.getReturnValue().lstDynamicCmpInputWrp,helper);
        }
        else if (state === "ERROR") 
            console.log(response.getError());
    },
    CreateDynamicArrayAndComponent : function(component,lstDynamicCmpInputWrp,helper){
        var componentArray = new Array();
        var componentName = "lightning:inputField";
        for(var i=0;i<lstDynamicCmpInputWrp.length;i++)
            componentArray.push([
                componentName , 
                helper.createAttributesObject(component,lstDynamicCmpInputWrp[i])
            ]);
        console.log(componentArray);
        helper.createComponents(component,componentArray);
    },
    createAttributesObject : function(component,objFieldSetMember){
        var obj = new Object();
        obj.value = component.getReference('v.objTestAccount.'+objFieldSetMember.APIName);
        obj.fieldName = objFieldSetMember.APIName; 
        return obj;
    },
    createComponents : function(component,componentArray){
        $A.createComponents(
            componentArray,
            function(objDynCmp, status, errorMessage){
                if (status === "SUCCESS")
                    component.set("v.body",objDynCmp);
                else 
                    console.log(status);
            }
        );
    }
})
```